# Storybook: Inject a mocked provider/service at component level

Tags: angular, ngrx, storybook, angular-storybook

I have an Angular component that has a component level provider.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'storybook-di-component',
  templateUrl: './di.component.html',
  providers: [{ provide: TEST_TOKEN, useValue: 123 }],
})
export class DiComponent {
  @Input()
  title: string;

  constructor(
    protected injector: Injector,
    protected elRef: ElementRef,
    @Inject(TEST_TOKEN) protected testToken: number
  ) {}
```

In such cases, how do I get storybook to inject a different provider so that I can provide an alternate/mock service? For example, in the DiComponent above, what if I wanted to inject `{ provide: TEST_TOKEN, useValue: 456 }` instead?

The real world use case is that I'm using ngrx/component-store and need to provide a dummy, prepopulated store for the component.

(Additional info:)
Injecting it at module level (like below) doesn't work as the component still goes and creates it's own instance of the provider:

```js
moduleMetadata: {
        providers: [
            { provide: StateStore, useValue: stateStore }
        ],
        imports: [...],
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem using a low tech approach.

1. Subclass the component in the `.stories.ts` file
2. In the sub class, declare the constructor to inject everything other than the service needing to be mocked.
3. Call `super(...)` with the injected services + the mocked service.

Given that my actual need was to inject a mock of the `ngrx/component-store` my `stories.ts` has something like the following now:

```js
const stateStore = new RecordSuggestionsPageStore(mockSuggestionsService);
stateStore.setState(() => ({
    selectableRecords: [
        { name: "John Legend", recordType: "employee" },
        { name: "Allan Davies", recordType: "employee" },
    ]
}));

@Component({
    selector: "myapp-suggested-records-page",
    templateUrl: "./suggested-records-page.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./suggested-records-page.component.scss"]
})
class SuggestedRecordsPageComponentStubbed extends SuggestedRecordsPageComponent {

    constructor(router: Router) {
        super(stateStore, router);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [TypeProvider](https://angular.io/api/core/TypeProvider) works for me. For your example it is something like the following, where the parameters for setState would need to match the method being mocked:

```typescript
class MockRecordSuggestionsPageStore implements Partial<RecordSuggestionsPageStore> {
  setState() {
    return [
      { name: "John Legend", recordType: "employee" },
      { name: "Allan Davies", recordType: "employee" },
    ]
  }
}
```

For providers in your story for SuggestedRecordsPageComponent

```typescript
    moduleMetadata: {
      declarations: [...],
      imports: [...],
      providers: [
        { provide: StateStore, useClass: MockRecordSuggestionsPageStore }
      ],
    },
```